# Injected beans are null after Tomcat restart with Spring and Axis2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, apache-axis

I have these beans:

```
<bean id="Child" class="test.Child"></bean>

<bean id="Parent" class="test.Parent">
    <property name="child" ref="Child" />
</bean>
```

I use Axis2, Spring with Hibernate on Tomcat. The Axis services are located in the Parent bean. It is mapped as SpringBeanName in the services.xml, including correct ServiceClass. I placed logs in the get and set methods for the Child beans variables inside the Parent bean:

```
private Child child;
public void setChild(Child child) {
   this.child = child;
   System.out.println(child);
}
public Child getChild() {
   System.out.println(child);
   return child;
}
```

I have a Spring initializing service called at startup, to load Spring in the startUp method in a service implementing ServiceLifeCycle.

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = service.getClassLoader();
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" }, false);
    applicationContext.setClassLoader(classLoader);
    applicationContext.refresh();
```

This is a simple example project, since the logic is quite more complex in real. Anyway, the result is:

- Deploy AAR in Axis2 war distribution's services, everything loads perfect, the set method is actually called with non null object.
- Every time the service is called, child is successfully read.

**The problem is when Tomcat get restarted. In the starting logs, the set method is called with non null object. But when the service is called - Null Pointer Exception, child is null. Redeploying the AAR makes everything working again. But after a new restart - the child is null again.**

**What is happening? Every help will be appreciated.**

- Note: I do not create the child with new. All scopes of the beans are default. I tried with prototype scope with no success. Session and request scopes threw an exception that these scopes are not recognized:

  No Scope registered for scope '...'
- Note 2: Uncommenting the  tag in the context.xml in the conf folder did not changed anything. I restarted Tomcat after the change.

Comment: Strange... I'm also waiting with curiosity for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, though, it does not cover all the range of situations. Changing the scope of the service in the `services.xml` from `application` to `request` (or the other two) fixes the problem which seems a bit logical.

**Note**: In case that `application` scope is what you really need, this fix is not applicable.